# Logistic Regression with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

Not sure if this is a great place for this question, but I was told CrossValidated was not. So, all these questions refer to sklearn, but if you have insights into logistic regression in general, I'd love to hear them as well.

1) Does data have to be standardizes(mean 0, stdev 1)? 
2) In sklearn, how do I specify what kind of regularization I want (L1 vs L2)? Note that this is different from penalty; penalty refers to classification error, not pentalty on coefficients.
3) How can I use to also do variable selection? I.e., analogously to lasso for linear regression. 
4) When using regularization, how do I optimize for C, the regularization strength? Is there something built-in, or do I have to take care of this myself?

Probably an example would be most helpful, but I'd appreciate any insights on any of these questions.

This has been my starting point: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) For logistic regression, no. You are not computing distances between instances.

2) You can specify the `penalty='l1'` or `penalty='l2'` parameter. See the [LogisticRegression page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). L2 penalty is default.

3) There are various explicit feature selection techniques that scikit-learn provides, e.g. using [SelectKBest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) with a [chi2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2) ranking function.

4) You will want to do a [Grid Search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV) for the optimal parameter.

For more detail on all these questions, I suggest going through some of the [Examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html), e.g. [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html#example-text-document-clustering-py) and [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#example-text-document-classification-20newsgroups-py).

Comment: Thank you. One matter of confusion is about 2): I think penalty is a different notion than regularization. I think penalty refers to the classification error penalty, not to the regularization penalty. Or am I confused?

Comment: Also, I thought you need normalization because, if you're going to use some regularization, i.e. lasso style, you need your input data to be normalized, no?

Comment: The parameters for logistic regression are learned via max (log) likelihood, so there's no question of linear or quadratic error penalties. If you're doing regularization, then yes you will probably want to standardize or normalize your data. You'll have to play around with it to see exactly which one (e.g. are there outliers).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, before I accept your answer, I've got some more questions. For example, you say above "if you're doing regularization, you need to standardize". But in sklearn, according to 2) above, you always do penalty='l1' or 'l2', doesn't this mean you always do regularization? How do you run in sklearn with no regularization? Would you mind posting a small code snippet that illustrated the various regularization usages?

Comment: @BaronYugovich sorry for the delay. It does indeed appear as if you must regularize in sklearn (you could potentially get around that somewhat by having an extremely small penalty constant). As for example code snippets, I highly suggest the tutorials.